# How to pass an array to a class?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Term;
class Polynomial;

class Term {
public:
  friend class Polynomial;
  void set_term(string s);
  int get_pow();
  int get_coefficient();

private:
  int coefficient;
  int pow;
};

class Polynomial {
public:
  friend class Term;
  Polynomial(int s, Term t[]);
  int get_size();
  Term *myterm;

private:
  int P_size;
};

void Term::set_term(string s) {
  coefficient = stoi(s.substr(1, 1));
  pow = stoi(s.substr(4, 1));
  if (s[0] == '-') {
    coefficient = -coefficient;
  }
}

int Term::get_coefficient() { return coefficient; }
int Term::get_pow() { return pow; }

Polynomial::Polynomial(int s, Term t[]) {
  P_size = s;
  myterm = new Term[s];
  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    myterm[i].coefficient = t[i].coefficient;
    cout << i << " Term " << t[i].coefficient << endl;
    cout << i << " Polynomial " << myterm[i].coefficient << endl;
    myterm[i].pow = t[i].pow;
  }
}

Polynomial::get_size() { return P_size; }

int main() {
  string x1;
  cin >> x1;
  int size_x1 = x1.size();

  Term term1[size_x1];

  for (int i = 0; i < size_x1; i += 5) {
    term1[i].set_term(x1.substr(i, 5));
  }

  Polynomial p1(size_x1 / 5, term1);
  for (int i = 0; i < size_x1; i += 5) {
    cout << term1[i].get_coefficient() << "x^";
    cout << term1[i].get_pow() << endl;
  }

  cout << "------------------" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < p1.get_size(); i++) {
    if (p1.myterm[i].get_coefficient() > 0)
      cout << "+";

    cout << p1.myterm[i].get_coefficient();
    cout << "x^";
    cout << p1.myterm[i].get_pow() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

term1 in main is working right but when I pass it to p1(Polynomial) just t[0] and, myterm[0]
 is true I mean I pass term1 to p1 as t so t[0] = term1[0] and myterm[0] = t[0]

```
Polynomial::Polynomial(int s, Term t[]) {
  P_size = s;
  myterm = new Term[s];

  for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    myterm[i].coefficient = t[i].coefficient;
    cout << i << " Term " << t[i].coefficient << endl;
    cout << i << " Polynomial " << myterm[i].coefficient << endl;
    myterm[i].pow = t[i].pow;
  }
}
```

---

in Polynomial constructor both t[1].coeffient and, myterm[1].coefficient are 4941660(for instance)
however, t is term1 and in term1 term1[1] is the 4(for instance)
if term1[1] is 4 so t[1] should be 4 but it's not so myterm[1], is not 4 too.

Comment: variable-length arrays `Term term1[size_x1]` are not part of the  C++ standard. You should use  `std::vector` instead also in the case of `new Term[s]` and  `std::vector` is the better option, and will make you life easier if you want to pass it to a function. Is there a reason why you don't want to use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of confusion over sizes here

```
string x1;
cin >> x1;
int size_x1 = x1.size();
Term term1[size_x1];

for (int i = 0; i < size_x1; i += 5) {
    term1[i].set_term(x1.substr(i, 5));
}
Polynomial p1(size_x1 / 5, term1);
```

You didn't say what your input is, but suppose it is `"1234567890"` then `size_x1` equals 10, so `term1` will also have size 10. Then your for loop will execute twice, with `i` equal to 0 and `i` equal to 5, so you will assign `12345` to `term1[0]` and `67890` to `term1[5]`. That makes no sense to me. `term1` has size 10 but the only elements assigned to are zero and five.

Then you create `p1` with size `size_x1/5` which equals 2. So the constructor for `p1` will look at `term1[0]` and `term1[1]`, but in the for loop you assigned to `term1[0]` and `term1[5]`.

You have to think carefully about what the code you are writing is actually doing. The compiler will do **exactly** what you tell it to. It's not like talking to a person who can understand what you really meant. So you have to be very careful. This is I think you really meant (but I could be wrong)

```
string x1;
cin >> x1;
int size_x1 = x1.size();
int size_term1 = size_x1/5;
Term term1[size_term1];

for (int i = 0; i < size_term1 ; ++i) {
    term1[i].set_term(x1.substr(5*i, 5));
}
Polynomial p1(size_term1, term1);
```

I created a new variable `size_term1` with the size of the term array, which is now the sizeof the input divided by 5. And I changed the for loop so that it assigns to `term1[0]` and `term1[1]`.

So your problem has nothing to do with passing an array to a class, which you did perfectly correctly. It was not thinking clearly about the code you were writing, and making mistakes in the logic.